# XSD for list objects

Tags: java, xsd

I am not sure I am doing this right if I want to get `List<UserModel>` response in XSD.

Let say, I have an user class like this:

```
public class UserModel {

    private String eMail;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private List<String> groups;
    private String lastUpdated;
    private String updatedBy;

    (assumed the getters and setters are already here...)

}
```

If I want to construct a XML schema (XSD) for SOAP, am I doing this correctly?

```
<xs:simpleType name="stringList">
    <xs:list itemType="xs:string"/>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:element name="userListEntity">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="userEntity"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="userEntity">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="groups" type="tns:stringList" />
        <xs:element ref="lastUpdated" />
        <xs:element ref="updatedBy" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="eMail" type="xs:string" use="required" />
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="lastUpdated" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="updatedBy" type="xs:string" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<xs:simpleType name="stringList">
    <xs:list itemType="xs:string"/>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:complexType name="userListEntity">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="userEntity" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tns:userEntity"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="userEntity">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="groups" type="tns:stringList" />
        <xs:element name="lastUpdated" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="updatedBy" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="eMail" type="xs:string" use="required" />
</xs:complexType>
```

i guess i solved it myself. i went to check at http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/#.UygxIvmSwUs and validation succeeded. i am not sure why reference could not be used when it is complextype. it told me 'ref' has no namespace found.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xs:element name="groups" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
```

Should solve your purpose